# Cannot inflate fragment. Receive: Binary XML file line #6: Class is not a View android.support.v4.app.DialogFragmen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, layout-inflater

I have FragmentActivity (from v4)
I'm trying to inflate DialogFragment.

**fragment_container**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/fragment_layout_container"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment android:id="@+id/fragment_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment>

</FrameLayout>
```

inflating by:

getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_container, null);

I receive:

01-12 10:53:01.627: E/AndroidRuntime(7676): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Class is not a View android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment
01-12 10:53:01.627: E/AndroidRuntime(7676):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:611)
01-12 10:53:01.627: E/AndroidRuntime(7676):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
01-12 10:53:01.627: E/AndroidRuntime(7676):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
01-12 10:53:01.627: E/AndroidRuntime(7676):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
01-12 10:53:01.627: E/AndroidRuntime(7676):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
01-12 10:53:01.627: E/AndroidRuntime(7676):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
01-12 10:53:01.627: E/AndroidRuntime(7676):     at com.tegrity.gui.BaseActivity.showFregmatDialog(BaseActivity.java:138)
01-12 10:53:01.627: E/AndroidRuntime(7676):     at com.tegrity.gui.BasePlayerActivity.waitingFollower(BasePlayerActivity.java:573)
01-12 10:53:01.627: E/AndroidRuntime(7676):     at com.tegrity.gui.BasePlayerActivity.access$0(BasePlayerActivity.java:564)
01-12 10:53:01.627: E/AndroidRuntime(7676):     at com.tegrity.gui.BasePlayerActivity$1.run(BasePlayerActivity.java:205)
01-12 10:53:01.627: E/AndroidRuntime(7676):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-12 10:53:01.627: E/AndroidRuntime(7676): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment cannot be cast to android.view.View
01-12 10:53:01.627: E/AndroidRuntime(7676):     at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:1259)
01-12 10:53:01.627: E/AndroidRuntime(7676):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)

Replacing android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment with fragment or android.support.v4.app.Fragment din't help.
cannot inflate using onCreateView ether.

please advice.

Comment: what you need top do tell me first

Answer (score 0):

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Class is not a
>   View android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment 01-12 10:53:01.627:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(7676): at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:611) 01-12
>   10:53:01.627

The exception states that the class you declared in the layout is not a subclass of `View`. To declare a subclass of a `Fragment` in a xml you have to use the `<fragment` tag. For instance

```
 <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment"
          android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

This will inflate the `HeadlinesFragment`, located in the package `com/example/android/fragments`, in your layout.

Comment: Still con not inflate.  receive android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment.... Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-12 12:26:54.128: E/AndroidRuntime(9321):  at com.tegrity.gui.AlertDialogFregmat.onCreateDialog(AlertDialogFregmat.java:61)...